# Loading images via AJAX into jQuery Supersized plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to dynamically load images via AJAX into the jQuery "Supersized" image slider: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

The AJAX call replaces the images fine, but the play button then becomes unresponsive, and subsequent calls disturb the slide interval timings (slides change faster).

I've tried all the answers (without luck) provided in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478178/calling-jquery-supersized-plugin-onclick/6584580#6584580) (same code). They suggested it could be a binding issue.

So in the html:

```
<a href="javascript:brown();">Doeet</a>
```

Ajax call:

```
function red(){
  $.ajax({
  url: 'ajax.php?action=brown',
  success: function(data){
  $('#script').html(data);
  }
  })
}
```

Ajax.php:

```
<?php switch($_GET["action"]){
  case "brown":
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
  jQuery(function($){
    $('#supersized').html('');
        $.supersized({          
            slides : [{image : 'image1.jpg'},
                       {image : 'image2.jpg'}]

            });     
    });</script>";
   break; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

do not try to pass the entire javascript code to transmit. only transmit the params u need:

```
function red(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php?action=brown',
    success: function(data){
      if (data != "") {
        $('#supersized').html('');
        $.supersized({          
          slides : [{image : data}],
          ....
        });   
      }
    }
  })
}
```

php:

```
<?php 
switch($_GET["action"]){
    case "brown":
    echo "imagename.jpg";
    break; 
}
?>
```

and may use

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
- http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I do that echo params with more than one image? Also, the playToggle button doesn't work after the call. I'll post a test link tomorrow

Comment: Test site at http://www.9crawford.com/slider/ ...when you click on "Doeet" the AJAX call works, next/prev navigation works, but the playToggle button doesn't

Comment: Sorry.. I have not seen the question. But I see you could solve the problem. For all googlers: instead of
`<a href="javascript:brown();">Doeet</a>` may use the click event of jquery. http://api.jquery.com/click/

With JSON u can simply transfer multidimensional arrays without any problem. 

and finaly: put the javascript to the bottom of your websites. This increases the performance of your websites.